# 你是第幾任總統/校長？How to translate this into English properly?

Tags: translation

```
你是第幾任總統/校長？
```

I'm a Chinese. Like the title suggests, I struggle to translate this into English. I struggled to find a translation for "任". Please help.

Comment: For translation questions, you need to try to find your own answer first; otherwise your question will probably be put on hold. Try sites such as iciba.com, google translate, and general web searches. If you can't find a good solution, come back here and edit your question to show us what you have tried.

Comment: @wpt If I could find that on iciba or Google Translate, would I even be asking here?!

Comment: iciba 1. What number President is Lincoln?
    林肯是第几任总统?

Comment: @user6065 I swear I didn't get that sentence when I used it lobg ago

Comment: it seems to be just colloquial English

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit awkward isn't it? ‘You are the how many'th President?

I suggest a rewording to something like (my Chinese is not good): 有多少总统您前？ That can easily be translated as 'How many Presidents have there been before you?'

Comment: I have thought of this,  but isn't it a bit weird? :/

Comment: Though the Chinese translation should be 您前面有多少位总统？

Comment: Hey Danny, I said my Chinese is not good! You are the Chinese, tell me what is correct, acceptable Chinese!

Comment: But how would you ask? Like if you don't know Obama's position. How manyth?

Comment: I'd put it as in my answer, "How many have there been before you?" You may hear people say "the how manyth", but it is not very good English, I would rephrase the question.

Comment: So would they answer "9" or "He is the 10th president"?

Comment: You said you were asking the President himself, not a third party. The answer might be: I am the 54th President of the People's Republic of America, there were 53 before me.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked up English StackExchange. Turned out someone has asked this already: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77222/how-do-you-convert-the-sentence-george-washington-was-the-first-president-to

Here is a list of possible questions:

- What number president are you?
- What is your position in the order of presidents?
- What is the ordinality of you in the sequence of presidents?

They should answer an ordinal number as answer.